# Bazel- Can I pass system property to test JVM (skylark rule)?

Tags: java, scala, bazel

I'm using `scala_specs2_junit_test` test rule and I want to pass the test a system property (what you can usually do with `-DmyProp=myValue`.
I found this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/tWP13lMKYb0) which sounds related but it talks about `java` (native rule which has access to command line arguments) and `run` (vs `test`).
Is this possible?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to pass these flags from the command line, and not from the BUILD file (see e.g. [java_test.jvm_flags](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/java.html#java_test.jvm_flags))?

Comment: Indeed that's what I mean. It's possible for java_test but not sure that for skylark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [--test_arg](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--test_arg), but the test rule itself must interpret such flags.

The `scala_specs2_junit_test` macro wraps a `scala_junit_test` rule. As a test rule, the latter must write `ctx.outputs.executable` (see [rule()#test](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/skylark/lib/globals.html#rule)) which is what Bazel executes upon `bazel test //my:test` and passes the `--test_arg` flags to.

I didn't find any logic in the Scala rules that would parse `--jvm_flags` flags, so it seems they need to be updated to handle that.

---

### Demo

<workspace>/my_test.bzl:

```
def _my_test_impl(ctx):
  ctx.file_action(
    ctx.outputs.executable,
    "\n".join([
        "#!/bin/bash",
        "echo \"DEBUG: Hello from $(basename $0)\"",
        "echo \"DEBUG: Argv=($@)\"",
        # Flag parsing (e.g. --jvm_flags) would have to happen here
    ]),
    True)

my_test = rule(
    implementation = _my_test_impl,
    test = True,
)
```

<workspace>/BUILD:

```
load("//:my_test.bzl", "my_test")

my_test(
    name = "my_test",
)
```

Output:

```
  $ bazel test //:my_test --test_output=streamed -t- --test_arg=--foo=bar --test_arg=--jvm_flags=blah
(...)
INFO: (14:45:05.379) Found 1 test target...
DEBUG: Hello from my_test
DEBUG: Argv=(--foo=bar --jvm_flags=blah)
Target //:my_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/my_test
INFO: (14:45:05.501) Elapsed time: 0.393s, Critical Path: 0.11s
INFO: (14:45:05.501) Build completed successfully, 3 total actions
//:my_test                                                               PASSED in 0.1s
```

EDIT: added comment to my_test.bzl to highlight where the flag parsing would happen

Comment: Thanks! Can you highlight in your skylark code what is the custom "logic"?

Comment: Done, added it to my_test.bzl

Comment: One more thing: in case of the native java_test rule, `--test_arg=--host_jvm_flags=-Dfoo` for example works only because (a) the executable of a java_test is a launcher shell script similar to what java_binary generates, and (b) that script understands the `--host_jvm_flags` flag and passes the value on to the JVM. There's no magic anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! for future reference: It's `--test_arg=--jvm_flags=-Dfoo` since `--host_jvm_flags` is for the Bazel process as the docs say. Additionally the scala junit test just uses the java test launcher so it has all the same capabilities with respect to that.

Comment: One last thing, do you know if it's documented for rule maintainers? It's important and if not I'll open a ticket

Comment: You're welcome! What do you mean by *it* in "do you know if it's documented for rule maintainers" ?

Comment: It==the need and maybe example of handling the parsing of the flags so that they support this capability

Comment: I don't know if this is documented, and I don't know where it should be. If you have any suggestion / idea, I'd appreciate hearing it. Even better, if you were willing to update the docs, I'd be more than happy to review the changes.

Answer (score -6):

You can always set a system property in Java programatically using System.setProperty(name, value).

The drawback to doing this in a unit test is that the property will stay set after the test. Make sure you set the value to null after the test.

Comment: Thanks but I'm asking on how to pass it from the outside (like a CI system) in *Bazel*

Comment: Can you please delete your answer? It has no relevance to my question